# IllegalArgumentException when attempting to import XLSX data into R

Tags: java, r, excel

While importing a xlsx file into R I faced the below error-

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\aniruddha\\Downloads\\failingExample.xlsx",1)
Error in .jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "getCell",  :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0
```

Can you please let me know the reason and the possible solution?

Comment: I faced the same error and removing cells borders formatting in the excel file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
 mydata <-read.xlsx2("C:\\Users\\aniruddha\\Downloads\\failingExample.xlsx",1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For no dependency on Java, you can use readxl.

```
Library(readxl)

mydata <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\aniruddha\\Downloads\\failingExample.xlsx")
```

Btw, instead of using \, you can also use a forward slash, like "C:/Users/aniruddha/Downloads/failingExample.xlsx"

Answer (score 2):

In my case `read.xlsx2` resulted in no error, but I got an empty `data.frame`.

Two other solutions:

1. deleting empty rows/columns
2. List item directly in excel specifying endRow

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped to solve the same issue:

> Exception: IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0

Here's the solution that worked out for me: 
I copied the full data from the input file, where i got this error (above mentioned), I created a new excel file, and pasted the data, and saved it and processed it. It just worked fine.

It might be a formatting issue. I'm not sure, but that's my guess. Because, the same data works fine in a new excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Myself had same issue. last cell is giving me the exception i observed last cell height is slightly different when compared with the other cell height.
adjusting the height of the cell to 15 solved the issue