# Using an .xlsx file as an input in a Shiny App

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I am working on a shiny app that requires a Excel with multiple sheets as an input. It was working well with the xlsx library and read.xlsx function. However, it returns the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0
```

I've now switched to gdata and read.xls, but I get a file path error every time I run the model.

I wonder if anyone dealt with this problem before and if there are any simple solutions to fix this problem.

EDIT:

The following code

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("uploadFile", "XLSX file"),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)

server <- function(input, output) ({

  dataset<-reactive({ 
    inFile <- input$uploadFile 
    dat<-read.xlsx(inFile$datapath, 1)
    return(dat)
  })

  output$summary <- renderText({summary(dataset())})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Returns:

```
Error : package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

If, instead I use

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("uploadFile", "XLSX file"),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary")
)

server <- function(input, output) ({

  dataset<-reactive({ 
    inFile <- input$uploadFile 
    dat<-read_excel(inFile$datapath, sheet =  1)
    return(dat)
  })

  output$summary <- renderText({summary(dataset())})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get:

```
Error: Missing file extension.
```

Comment: Can you post parts of your code that caused this error?

Comment: have a look at {readxl} package

Comment: So it *was* working well and then suddenly it *stopped working at all*. So something changed. What? Is it only on some XLS files? Does it work outside of shiny? Has some package or R been upgraded?

Comment: Yes, I've upgraded my RStudio, and  based on this answer [link]
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314787/illegalargumentexception-when-attempting-to-import-xlsx-data-into-r) it seems that it could be the source of the problem. But that should not explain why the problem happens in the app version in the Shiny server, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using readxl)*

The *datapath* column from `input$uploadFile` is a path to a temp file which has no extension. So **read_excel()** does not know what format it is.

Use **read_xlsx()** instead:

`dat <- read_xlsx(inFile$datapath, sheet =  1)`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked fine for me.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
    list(
        ui = fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Use readxl"),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                              accept = c(".xlsx")
                              )
                    ),
                mainPanel(
                    tableOutput('contents'))
                )
            ),
        server = function(input, output){
            output$contents <- renderTable({
                inFile <- input$file1

                if(is.null(inFile))
                    return(NULL)
                file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                          paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
                read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
            })
        }
        )
    )
```

Also, see this.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html